# Does texlive installation shows the package name those are installing?

Tags: packages, installing

When I start texlive installation using `./install-tl` following [tug.org](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) installation instruction I see some output looks like --

```
Installing to: /usr/local/texlive/2016
Installing [0001/3406, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: 12many [376k]
Installing [0002/3406, time/total: 00:11/19:21:11]: 2up [66k]
Installing [0003/3406, time/total: 00:17/25:28:14]: Asana-Math [482k]
Installing [0004/3406, time/total: 00:27/19:19:14]: ESIEEcv [137k]
Installing [0005/3406, time/total: 00:38/23:41:21]: FAQ-en [4971k]
```

Is these name are package name?
Is the total package number 3406 that are being installed?

Comment: yes but these are texlive installation packages not necessarily the name of latex packages. (Asana-Math for example is a font)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B not today actually, travelling, but don't we have an answer somewhere explaining difference between "package" for latex, ctan, texlive, and linux package managers (we should have if we haven't:-)